# Loading flask configuration using from_object

Tags: python, flask

[The documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Config.from_object) to `flask.Config.from_object` says:

> You should not use this function to load the actual configuration but rather configuration defaults. The actual config should be loaded with from_pyfile() and ideally from a location not within the package because the package might be installed system wide.

Why should I not use this function to load the actual configuration? And why should the actual configuration be loaded using `from_pyfile` and from a location not within the package?

Note that [*Flask Web Development*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920031116.do) seems to use `from_object` to load the actual configuration (p. 78-79):

> The configuration settings stored in one of the classes defined in `config.py` can be imported directly into the application using the `from_object()` method
>   available in Flask’s `app.config` configuration object.

```
# code excerpt from the book:
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
config[config_name].init_app(app)
```

Comment: My opinion: maybe block `Error output` (Ignore all exceptions)!